# Wave equation transverse wave

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

So guys my question is that when we consider the a sinusoidal wave equation of a transverse wave, for example $$y=A \sin(\omega t-kx)$$ then let's say at $x=L$ and at time $t=0$ when the wave has not even been produced, why are we getting the value of $y$ as $-A\sin (kL)$ because practically if we think about it we know that the wave has not yet reached that point so do we say that equation is valid only when $t>Kx/\omega$?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The equation you mention is the one of a harmonic 1D wave. These waves are considered to be infinite (they have no beginning or end at any side).

However, real events are not like this. Every phenomenon you want to describe will probably emit a wave or a pulse starting at some time and from a certain position. Consequently, any real wave is different, so it's said that pure sine waves "do not exist" in real life.

And nevertheless

1. They're usually a very good approximation
2. Most phenomena can be described as a superposition of these waves. Any wave can be made of by adding pure sine waves, so we can use them to de-compose the real wave into many frequencies. This is called Fourier decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation of a wave describes the behavior of a wave, wich at the time t=0 already exists and stretches in all direction x. It does not describe the creating of a wave by a periodic signal at a special place.Do it describes hast the displacement at x=L at the time t=0 or any other time, even in negativ time.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression describes a plane wave that exists everywhere at all times. Obviously such a waves cannot exist as it would have infinite energy and also it would ever have been emitted nor will it ever be absorbed. In short it does not describe interaction between charges.

Thus your expression is an approximation that is no longer valid near the spacetime point where it was emitted or where it will, if ever, be absorbed.